# What does the "s" mean in the following permission:"-rwsr-x---"

Tags: permissions

I know about the different permissions and how to change permissions, etc. But I have just seen one of my files has the permissions:

> -rwsr-x--- 1 root  scott 26974 Dec  8  2010 extjob

What does the "s" mean, in the permissions?

There is another question on [U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67671/how-to-suid-iwconfig-on-debian-wheezy) that has a little to do with the same permissions, but doesn't explain what they mean.

Comment: Read : man chmod

Comment: Thanks @Vinz. Just checked it, and it shows: `set user or group ID on execution (s)`.

Comment: Rather: read `man ls`, which doesn't have the answer but refers you to `info ls` for more information; `info ls` has the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is setuid. You can refer to this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) to get more details.

You can also try `man setuid`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, if I knew it was called setuid or setgid, then I would've Googled it, myself. So I do appreciate you telling me what it is.